# How to automatically encrypt asp.net project before publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developer and create web application with Asp.net MVC and use publish to upload project output in web server.
How to protect all dll files in bin folder from obfuscators before publish project

Comment: Encrypt **.dll files**? Why?

Comment: If someone has access to your DLL files, you've already been owned. That they're encrypted will be the most minor of issues to anyone who has already compromised your site. Your DLL files are not publicly visible (unless you have a very strange setup on your web-server), so "encrypting" (obfuscating) them is pointless.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno I edit my question text protect dll from obfuscators

Comment: How will anyone get hold of these DLL files? They're on a webserver, not publicly accessible.

Comment: Do you mean protect it from decompiling? and as @spender said, the `bin/` folder isn't served (assuming you're using IIS).

Comment: What they're saying is, if someone found a way to access your DLL's, they've already hacked you. The DLLs aren't accessible otherwise, like how a SWF would be. They're never sent to the client.

Comment: @scheien yes protect from decompile

Comment: @spender i want protect  dll from web server admin

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET obfuscation tools/strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy)

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are trying to Encrypt or somewhat meaning as protect your dll , (protecting from Obfuscators? , check meaning of that)

You cannot fully protect your DLL if they are accessible, they can be decompile somehow, but you can try with some good Obfuscators, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET and [SIGN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975723/c-why-sign-an-assembly) it.

Comment: Thank you for answer what tools is best for use in Visual Studio?I want free tools

Comment: I have no idea but found this one, https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/releases OpenSource