# Entity Framework DefaultDBModelStore - Could not find assembly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

So I'm looking to improve Entity Framework start up time performance by following this article:

https://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/3-steps-for-fast-entityframework-6.1-code-first-startup-performance/

I built the custom branch of the entity framework project into a dll

I added the dll to my web forms project and everything works great! Startup time is improved

However I also have a Web API project in my solution and when I add the custom entity framework dll I get this error : "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key"

I've followed same steps for both projects, not sure why web forms projects works and web api doesn't

Also note, both projects live in the same solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign your custom Entity Framework dll. You cannot reference an unsigned assembly with signed assemblies. More info: 
[C#: why sign an assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975723/c-why-sign-an-assembly)

Comment: But why does it work for the web forms project unsigned?

Comment: from unsigned you can add unsigned reference but in singed project you cannot add unsigned reference. just test it you can sing your assembly in 5 min and test it