# Stealing passwords via DLL injection?

Tags: c#, security, xamarin, encryption, dll

We have a couple places in our app (Xamarin C# cross-platform) where we deal with sensitive information - so we've password-protected the database (SQLCipher) and we encrypt the data we store outside of the database.  However, I'm thinking that it wouldn't be difficult for a determined hacker to inject a DLL between our app and the database DLL and see the password going by in the Connect() function, and likewise to inject a DLL between our app and whichever system DLL provides System.Security.Cryptography and see our AES key going by.

Is there a way to protect against this?  Or am I incorrect and this isn't actually a big security risk?

Comment: the app package is signed, you can't dynamically change code without breaking the signature.  I think the security risk is pretty low, but you have to evaluate that based on your client's tolerance, etc.

Comment: Raymond Chen calls this "being on the other side of the airtight hatch".  When somebody has sufficient rights to copy a malicious DLL into the install folder and induce your program to load it then he won't bother doing it the hard way.  He'll simple replace your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, that the all what you need is to sign your assemblies "[C#: why sign an assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975723/c-why-sign-an-assembly)".